# How to switch views without the store switcher?

Tags: magento-2.1, store-view

I have set up a view that has different settings that we want to use for our own purposes but we dont want customers to see it.

I have removed the store switcher control from the template.  How can we manually switch store views ourselves without having the control there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this part to your URL:

```
/en/?___from_store=fr
```

For example, here the current store view is `en`, and the previous view was `fr`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this URL: `http://yoursite.com/stores/store/switch/?___store=yourviewcode`.
This manually switches the store view.

Comment: I cant get this to work, it just directs me back to root url without switching the view

Comment: It works in my 2.1.8 installation. The answer from mehdi didn't work for me but apparently it did for you. weird...

Comment: strange, I am using 2.1.8 also